# I Can't Login To Website [urllib, urllib2]

Tags: python, python-2.7, authentication, urllib2, urllib

Website : https://login.metu.edu.tr/cas/login

My Code :

```
   cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
   opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
   opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
   urllib2.install_opener(opener)
   authentication_url = 'https://login.metu.edu.tr/cas/login'
   payload = {
      'username':username,
      'password':password,
      'lt':'A', # this is changing
      'execution':'e4s1',
      '_eventId':'submit'
            }
   data = urllib.urlencode(payload)
   req = urllib2.Request(authentication_url, data)
   resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

There is no error. Just, I can't login. What is the problem ? Is there anything missing ?

Comment: Do you get a response back from the website? I'm assuming 403 if anything.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't login"?  What happens when you run the program?

Comment: It is redirecting me to the same page. (Here : https://login.metu.edu.tr/cas/login)

Comment: I am trying login and (even it's not login) trying go there 

http://net.ncc.metu.edu.tr/kota/kota_intranet.php

but it is redirecting me here again

https://login.metu.edu.tr/cas/login.php

I think there is something missing or wrong about "payload" variables. Can anybody check them ?